# Can i compare two bytes values on basis of nearly equal to in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, comparison, swift4.2

i have two values in bytes in two different variables . i want to perform a certain action whenever values are nearly equal to each other.
I there any method in swift in which i can perform any action on variables values nearly equal to.
If recommend me some code , tutorial or article to achieve this.
I am new to swift so please avoid down voting.

Comment: For what purpose you have to compare your bytes Values??? Mean What are you trying to implement?

Comment: well i just want to know i there any comparison method available for nearly equal to ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let string1 = "Hello World"
let string2 = "Hello"
let byteArrayOfString1: [UInt8] = string1.utf8.map{UInt8($0)} //Converting HELLO WORLD into Byte Type Array
let byteArrayOfString2: [UInt8] = string2.utf8.map{UInt8($0)} //Converting HELLO into Byte Type Array

if byteArrayOfString1 == byteArrayOfString2 {
    print("Match")
}else {
    print("Not Match")

}
```

For more Help, Visit https://medium.com/@gorjanshukov/working-with-bytes-in-ios-swift-4-de316a389a0c

Comment: i don't want to check exact equal to i want to approximately equal to

Comment: In Any programming language, Right now there is not any Function/Approach that can tell you approximately Comparison I THINK...  You only can Compare Float Type values approximately...

Answer (score 0):

well exactly i don't think so there is such method that compare approx values but if you discuss what exactly you want to do we can find a better alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution:

```
func nearlyEqual(a: Float, b: Float, epsilon: Float) -> Bool {
let absA = abs(a)
let absB = abs(b)
let diff = abs(a - b)
if a == b {
    return true
} else if (a == 0 || b == 0 || absA + absB < Float.leastNonzeroMagnitude) {
    // a or b is zero or both are extremely close to it
    // relative error is less meaningful here
    return diff < (epsilon * Float.leastNonzeroMagnitude)
} else {
    return diff / (absA + absB) < epsilon
}
}
```

Then you can use it like :

```
    print(nearlyEqual(a: 1.2, b: 1.4, epsilon: 0.2))
```

This will return true.